# any npm module to repeat a task every day at given time in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm Looking for any NPM Module to use in Nodejs app, to send notification through 
email and SMS every morning at the 9am local time.

any solutions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 00 9 * * 1-7', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every day
   * at 9:00:00 AM.
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

use `node-cron` module for more info: [node-cron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)